# How to solve int value to null in RESTful API update situation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Sorry for bad english.

I currently use dto for request body mapping,

Spring can not know input is null or not received, because both situation is just null.

As an example, Like this.

```
// dto
public class UpdateDto {
  private String name;
  private Integer price;
}

// entity
public class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  private Integer price;
}
```

I solved in string case using empty string. When empty string received, update this field to null. Because most of case empty string can treated as null.

```
// update name
if (updateDto.getName() != null) {
  if (updateDto.getName() == "") {
    // set name to null
  } else {
    // just update to getName() value
  }
}

// update price
// when i set to null?
```

However integer case, I don't know how can i solve this problem.
Anything good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution.

related link(In korean): https://www.it-gundan.com/ko/java/spring-rest-controller%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%EB%B6%80%EB%B6%84-%EC%97%85%EB%8D%B0%EC%9D%B4%ED%8A%B8%EC%97%90-%EB%8C%80%ED%95%B4-null-%EA%B0%92%EA%B3%BC-%EC%A0%9C%EA%B3%B5%EB%90%98%EC%A7%80-%EC%95%8A%EC%9D%80-%EA%B0%92%EC%9D%84-%EA%B5%AC%EB%B3%84%ED%95%98%EB%8A%94-%EB%B0%A9%EB%B2%95/827265839/

the solution is, add dirty check boolean flag in setter.
in case of above,

```
// dto
public class UpdateDto {
  private String name;
  private Integer price;
  private Boolean isPriceDirty;

  // when setter setPrice,
  public void setPrice(Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
    this.isPriceDirty = true;
  }
}
```

then, output can set null only when dirty is true.

Comment: I haven't found anything better than this way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use primitive data type `int` and set nullable as `false` since `null` doesn't make sense for numbers

use primitive data type for `price` in both `entity` and `dto`
Entity:

```
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private int price;
```

DTO:

```
 private int price;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I don't understand that this answer is not what i intend to.
My problem is in dto, not entity.